# how to get custom table data in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get my custom table data on frontend but i was not getting any success please suggest me  by looking at below code thanks in advance

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Postform extends Template
{


        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'quickrfq/google_options/googlepublickey';
        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME = 'quickrfq/google_options/theme';
        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE = 'quickrfq/google_options/captchastatus';

        const CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD = 'quickrfq/upload/allow';

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {

        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->_connection = $resource->getConnection();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getTableData()
    {
        $myTable = $this->_connection->getTableName('fme_quickrfq');
        $sql     = $this->_connection->select()->from(
             ["tn" => $myTable]
        ); 
        $result  = $this->_connection->fetchAll($sql);
        return $result;

        //print_r($result);
    }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('quickrfq/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
    }



    public function getCaptchaTheme()
    {

        $theme = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME);
        return $theme;
    }

    public function isCaptchaEnable()
    {

        $enable = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE);
        return $enable;
    }

    public function getAllowedFileExtensions()
    {

        $ext = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD);
        return $ext;
    }
    public function getPublicKey()
    {

        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY);
    }
}
```

**now in phtml file**

```
<?php


 $myTabledata = $block->getTableData();
    print_r($myTabledata);

?>
```

**update**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Postform extends Template
{


        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'quickrfq/google_options/googlepublickey';
        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME = 'quickrfq/google_options/theme';
        const CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE = 'quickrfq/google_options/captchastatus';

        const CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD = 'quickrfq/upload/allow';

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {

        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getTableData()
    {
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName   = $connection->getTableName('fme_quickrfq');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName;
        $results = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);
        return $result;
    }

    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('quickrfq/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
    }



    public function getCaptchaTheme()
    {

        $theme = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_THEME);
        return $theme;
    }

    public function isCaptchaEnable()
    {

        $enable = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_ENABLE);
        return $enable;
    }

    public function getAllowedFileExtensions()
    {

        $ext = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_FILE_EXT_UPLOAD);
        return $ext;
    }
    public function getPublicKey()
    {

        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::CONFIG_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Postform extends Template
{
    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {

        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getTableData()
    {
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName   = $connection->getTableName('fme_quickrfq');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $tableName;
        $results = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->fetchAll($query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Make sure data available in table.**

Remove generated and clean cache.

Comment: then how to use it in phtml file??

Comment: No need to change in phtml file. Your phtml file code you can use. Just need to change in block

Comment: ok let me try give me a min

Comment: this is not working in my case

Comment: check your db data available or not and did you call your block in layout?

Comment: yes i did and there is data in table i have checked it using object manager

Comment: Please match your namespace with my answer.

Comment: wait am updating ans with my block code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105118/discussion-between-pramod-and-rohan-hapani).